# options.filter() is not a function in MUI autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, material-ui, autocomplete, mern

I am trying to create an autocomplete function in MERN stack and am using MUI autocomplete. I keep getting this error when I type anything in the box

`** useAutocomplete.js:201 Uncaught TypeError: options.filter is not a function**`

My code is below, the backend is functioning perfectly and returns an the data to the frontend successfully.

``

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
    import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
    import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
    import SearchService from '../../services/search.services';
    import Select from 'react-select';

    export default function Search() {
     const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);  
     const [value, setValue] = useState(null);  
    useEffect(() => {
     SearchService.get()
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.data)
        setOptions(response.data.data);
      });
      console.log(options)
    }, []);

   const handleInputChange = async (value, event) => {
    // Update options list based on input value
    console.log(value)
    const updatedOptions = await SearchService.get(value);
    setOptions(updatedOptions);
    console.log(options)
    }

   return (
    <Stack spacing={2} sx={{ width: 300 }}>
         <Autocomplete
      filterOptions={(x) => x}
      options={!options ? [{label: 'Loading...', id: 0}] : options}
      value={value}
      onInputChange={(event, newValue) => {
        handleInputChange(newValue)
      }}
      
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Select an option"
          variant="outlined"
        />
      )}
    />
    </Stack>
      );
     }
```

``

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried using other stackoverflow questions that were similar, I tried using the documentation and nothing works. I tried different iterations of the same things but nothing will fix this.

Comment: Could you share result of the console.log(updatedOptions)?

Comment: thats actually part of the problem, it logs nothing and does not appear to fire

Comment: Try debugging deeper in SearchService.get(value). Set console.log inside the SearchService.get. 
You can add condition like `setOptions(Array.isArray(updatedOptions) ? updatedOptions : [])` and that should avoid the error. But you still have to find the source of the problem